# Using -exec option with Find command in Bash

Tags: linux, find, exec

I am trying to use the -exec option with the find command to find specific files in my massive panoramas directory and move them to a specified location. The command I am using below passes an error argument not found for -exec. Can somebody point out my error in parsing the command? Or would I have to create a pipe of some sorts instead?

$ find -name ~/path_to_directory_of_photos/specific_photo_names* -exec mv {} ~/path_to_new_directory/

Comment: Maybe move this over to serverfault?

Comment: I voted to migrate to SuperUser.Com, but it actually would be more appropriate on Unix.StackExchange.Com.

Answer (score 7):

You need to terminate your exec'ed command with an escaped semicolon (`\;`).

Comment: Ok thank you, missed a space at the end between ~/path_to_new_directory and \; that was tripping me up. Solved.

Answer (score 3):

You should quote the name pattern otherwise the shell will expand any wildcards in it, before running `find`. You also need to have a semicolon (backslashed to avoid the shell interpreting it as a command separator) to indicate the end of the `mv` command.

The correct command would be:

```
find ~/path_to_directory_of_photos -name "specific_photo_names*" -exec mv {} ~/path_to_new_directory \;
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this post is old, but here's my answer in case it helps anyone else.  See the background from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12060557/solution-to-error-find-missing-argument-to-exec-with-find-exec-cp-target/12060558#12060558).  If you end the command with + instead of \; you can run it much more efficiently.  \; will cause "mv" to be executed once per file, while + will cause "mv" to be executed with the maximum number of arguments.  E.g.

```
mv source1 destination/
mv source2 destination/
mv source3 destination/
```

vs.

```
mv source1 source2 source3 destination/
```

The latter is much more efficient.  To use +, you should also use --target-directory.  E.g.

```
find ~/path_to_directory_of_photos -name "specific_photo_names*" -exec mv --target-directory="~/path_to_new_directory" {} +
```