# -Exec is missing argument in find command (difference between \; and +)

Tags: bash, shell, find, arguments, exec

To start with, I've read related subjects, but none of them has explained my doubts.

I have a following command which works fine:

```
find ./source/ -maxdepth 1 -type f ! -name "secretinfo.md" -exec cp {} ./build/ \;
```

However, using `;` means that I'm passing every found file to the cp command one by one. I thought I could pass them all at once as cp command allows that. Based on other answear that I've found:

> A -exec command must be terminated with a ; (so you usually need to
>   type \; or ';' to avoid interpretion by the shell) or a +. The
>   difference is that with ;, the command is called once per file, with
>   +, it is called just as few times as possible (usually once, but there is a maximum length for a command line, so it might be split up) with
>   all filenames

Since that's what I did:

```
find ./source/ -maxdepth 1 -type f ! -name "secretinfo.md" -exec cp {} ./build/ +
```

And here I'm getting an error:

```
find: missing argument to `-exec'
```

Can you explain to me why this is not allowed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`+` is ok, but your use of parameter with exec is not correct.

you may try:

```
find ./source/ -maxdepth 1 -type f ! -name "secretinfo.md" -exec bash -c 'cp $@ ./build/' - {} +
```

or

```
find ./source/ -maxdepth 1 -type f ! -name "secretinfo.md" -exec cp --target-directory=./build/ {} +
```

Despite it may not be rely satisfying, the reason for `why` is that like this may be `because it is supposed to`; in the `man find` you may see:

> -exec command {} +

and you may notice the command is *before* the `{} +` (which is somehow harcdoded in this syntax).

I must say, I don't know why it specified like this (seems to be posix: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/find.html)

see also

[Solution to error 'find: missing argument to -exec' with find -exec cp {} TARGET_DIR +](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12060557/solution-to-error-find-missing-argument-to-exec-with-find-exec-cp-target/12060558)

for some other examples, see [find: missing argument to -exec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2961673/find-missing-argument-to-exec)